# Python - How to select ObjectId

Tags: python, pymongo

Python noob here. I have the following in my database in an object called "data" and I want to write some python that will select the lowest score from each group of student_id....and grab the unique ObjectId for each minimum record found?

```
{u'student_id': 197, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb88d'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 10.90872422518918}
{u'student_id': 197, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb88e'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 88.3871242475841}
{u'student_id': 198, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb892'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 17.46279901047208}
{u'student_id': 198, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb891'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 76.18366499496366}
{u'student_id': 199, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb895'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 49.34223066136407}
{u'student_id': 199, u'_id': ObjectId('50906d7fa3c412bb040eb896'), u'type': u'homework', u'score': 58.09608083191365}
```

Thank you for your trouble....here is my code...

```
import pymongo

from itertools import groupby
from pymongo import Connection


connection = Connection('localhost', 27017)

db = connection.students

data = db.grades.find({'type' : 'homework'}).sort([('student_id',pymongo.ASCENDING),('score',pymongo.ASCENDING)])



for student_id, items in groupby(data, lambda s: s['student_id']):
    lowest_score = min(i['score'] for i in items)

    print lowest_score
```

Comment: so what part do you need help on? Can you narrow it down?

Comment: I can print out the lowest score per student but now I need to grab the unique ObjectId for each lowest_score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be able to do your minimum check differently and get the ObjectID rather than the score from the minimum value. Here's how I'd do it:

```
lowest_id = min(items, key=lambda i: i['score'])['_id']
```

Now, it's possible (indeed, likely) that you can do something similar in the database itself, and probably that will have better performance. However, the above may work just fine if your data set is not too unwieldy.

Comment: yep, I was about to answer that.. this is definitely the right way

Comment: yep...this one seems to be it.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you still have access to the student_id field, if so you could replace:

```
lowest_score = min(i['score'] for i in items)
```

with:

```
lowest_score = min((i['score'],i['student_id']) for i in items)
```

Comment: (min will compare the first element in each tuple)

Comment: ah...I just stumbled on this also...so then how would I say ...print or isolate the student_id at that point? (thank you again for your time)

Comment: `student_id = lowest_score[1]`

Comment: `lowest_score = lowest_score[0]`, I probably should have renamed the tuple in the statement above